# C# - JObject modifyied the time stamp in the post request payload

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, timestamp

I have this Web Api controller:

```
 [Route("api/v1/GitHubEvents/{Id}/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostGitHubEvent([FromBody]JObject value, long id)
    { ...
      gitHubEventAuthenticator.ValidateSignature(...);
    }
```

When the Post request comes from machine with different local time than the controller's timezone, the signature validation fails because of mismatch between the original request's time stamp and the time stamp after serialized by the JObject (or anything else from the IIS/Web Api environment).

Can you please suggest way to keep the original time stamp without modifying it by the JObject/Environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting DateFormatHandler

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.Unspecified
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Where I'll set this configuration?

Comment: @Roni you using Newtonsoft.Json (or JSON.NET), right? I've assumed this from you using JObject class.

Comment: You are right. But I don't understand where i can use the above setting, since the modifying of the time stamp occurs in the first line of the code `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostGitHubEvent([FromBody]JObject value, long id)` and that changes the content of the request and leads to signature validation failure. So maybe is there a way to set the above setting in the higher level?

Comment: @Roni how did you set up using Json.net as default json formatter in Web Api? Did you do that?

Comment: I didn't put it. Sould it be done in `WebApiConfig.cs` ? Thanks!